# how to auto symbolicate Crash Log

Tags: iphone, symbolicate, symbolicatecrash, plcrashreporter

I use PLCrashReport to save crash file and send it to server, when i get crash log file , i have to symbolicate each of the crash logs file to understand this error by terminal.But this work take alot of time because if i release my app to appstore, i will get alot of crash from users. So i want to create a app can auto symbolicate crash file, can i do it ?
I am not sure but i have to use terminal window to symbolicate crash and i think make a app like this very difficult, example for symbolicate command

```
symbolicatecrash log_e371b6ac-6f46-4408-90df-ea0ff96ce50e_2012.07.26_07.34.22.log.crash -v result.crash
```